# How do I extract the key from a key-value pair (character = character) in R?

Tags: r, key-value

I have this variable

```
variable_pairs <- c("var_name1" = "var_id1", "var_name2" = "var_id2")
```

I need to extract the names, and strip the quotes, so I get something like `(var_name1, var_name2)`

Is there something to this effect in r? I suspect this is easier done in Python, but I have to do it in R. Also I'm an absolute R beginner.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: making my purpose a bit clearer.

I need to send the names in the `select = c(year, *indicator_vector_name*)`part. I firstly had to do it manually (`select = c(year, *total_population, gdp*)`) but it's obviously not good. The 'mmr' object then goes to a ggplot function.

```
indicator_vector <- c('total_population'='SP.POP.TOTL', 'gdp' = 'NY.GDP.MKTP.CD', 'gdp_growth' ='NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG', 'fertility_rate' ='SP.DYN.TFRT.IN', 'pop_growth'='SP.POP.GROW', 'pop_0_14'='SP.POP.0014.TO.ZS', 'pop_65plus'='SP.POP.65UP.TO.ZS', 'trade_ratio' ='NE.TRD.GNFS.ZS')

indicator_vector_name <- noquote(names(indicator_vector))


for (i in indicator_vector){
  indicator_data <- WDI(indicator = indicator_vector, country = c(country), start = start, end= end)
}

mmr <- melt(subset(indicator_data, select = c(year, indicator_vector_name)), id.vars = "year")
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to strip the quotes? `names(variable_pairs)` would give you the names of the vector, to strip quotes you can do `noquote(names(variable_pairs))`

Comment: I need to insert the names as object names into a melt function in order to produce multiple graphs on the same coordinates system. EDIT: added a few more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change variable name without quotes. Try this :

```
indicator_vector_name <- names(indicator_vector)
mmr <- melt(indicator_data[c('year', indicator_vector_name)], id.vars = "year")
```

Comment: It works! Many thanks! Sorry for coming with such simple problems and thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
indicator_data %>% 
  select(year, all_of(names(indicator_vector)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -year)
```